# SERVERPROPERTY('SERVERNAME') v/s 'localhost'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have created an SQL Job that fetches data from database tables and writes it to output file i.e. CSV on specific location.

For this I am using `bcp` and `xp_cmdshell`.

In `bcp` I need to pass the server name. Upto this I was using `'localhost'` as server name, but by running this on another PC I have came to know that the `'localhost'` login is not working on it so that the output files are not getting generated.

I searched about it and got another command that returns the server name along with server instance. i.e. `SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName')`

Now I am confused for using it. It is running OK with my local PC and Another PC also but my question is - Is it always run safely without any error if I put it on any other Server or PC? Which one of this is advisable to be used?

Comment: show the commands you're using

Comment: @JotaBe That doesn't make any sense, the commands are working fine. The issue is with server name on my local PC as I am not able to login to SQL Server with name "localhost". If I use the server name along with instance name then every thing is working fine. And SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') is giving me the same. The thing I want to know is whether it will work OK with every environment where I deploy it? OR SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') will also give an error like "localhost" giving me on some cases? And which one is advisable to be used?

Comment: It's not a question of making sense. I can't figure how you're running BCP, where is the job, how you call it from the other PCs... I suppose nonone else knows it, so expect no help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting confused about the term "LocalHost".  This is just an alias (aka loopback) that points back to the machine originating the connection.

For example, if my machine was named MYMACHINE and I was running a default instance on it, I could connect to the database either by specifying LocalHost or MYMACHINE and I would connect.  If someone else was trying to connect from machine YOURMACHINE, they would only be able to connect to my database if they specified MYMACHINE.  If they entered LOCALHOST it would try to connect to YOURMACHINE as that is where the connection is originating.

Back to your question now, yes, it is safe to get the servername value from SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') as it will always report the correct and current network name of the server.  This is not the case with @@SERVERNAME, so you should shy away from that for your purposes.

LocalHost: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

@@ServiceName (last paragraph of remarks section is important): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187944.aspx

P.S. I apologize for not adding a comment to the question, but my reputation is not currently high enough to do so.